# How is :contains() supposed to be used?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm new to jQuery, but just attempting to create a function I can use to filter a table.  I've got the table set up so that I can select all the rows by the class (which works fine) and call each() on the result.  Inside the callback to each() I've got this if statement:

```
if ($(this).find("td[name=firstName]:contains('ke')").size() > 0)
```

However it doesn't find a match when I know it's there.  If I take out the contains() call it does find the table cell, however so I'm really not sure what's wrong.  Unfortunately (for me) this could be as simple as using the wrong syntax... :(

The end result would be to have a variable for the selector string, but since even using the string directly isn't working...

Comment: What is your intention? It's hard to tell whether you're doing it right, if we don't know what it is you want to do. :) You can leave out the single quotes, btw, so your selector becomes `"td[name=firstName]:contains(ke)"`. It selected all td-elements that have a name-attribute with value "firstName", and the text node content of the td element has to contain the string 'ke'. P.S.: You're also using `.find()`, which searches in the offspring elements of `$(this)`, **not including $(this)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend jQuery's selectors with this:

```
$.expr[':'].icontains = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
return (obj.textContent || obj.innerText || jQuery(obj).text() || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(meta[3].toLowerCase()) >= 0;
};
```

That would give you a new pseudo-selector `:icontains(text)` that works like `:contains(text)`, but case-insensitive.

See: [Comment Section](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) on jQuery's documentation page for `:contains(text)`

Answer (score 1):

replace `.size()` with `.length`

also check that it is finding lowercase 'ke'

Comment: I have to run so I can't check, but that's very likely the problem.  How do I g et a case insensitive contains?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me (http://jsfiddle.net/dactivo/PHMkx/).

It looks for a td with an attribute "name" with value "FirstName" and inside the td, that's to say, the html inside td, contains the string "prueba". size() or length here both work.

```
<table><tr><td name="FirstName"><a class="edit">prueba</a> </td></tr></table>

$(document).ready(function(){

    if ($("table:eq(0)").find("td[name=FirstName]:contains('prueba')").size() > 0)
  {
      alert("yes");
  }

});
```